# Is there a way to turn a way to transform .scala file to .class file?

Tags: file, scala, class, jar

I have some .scala files that I want to package up into a .jar how can I turn them into .class files?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. This is a valid question for a beginner.

Comment: @Tilo because it shows that the questioner hasn't conducted any research whatsoever.

Comment: @Daenyth - I see your point, but conducting that research would require to know the term "compile" - so at this level I still tend to find a down vote unfairly discouraging.

Comment: @Tilo "getting started" http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run scalac on them. If you're using a build manager like maven or sbt, use the appropriate compile command.

I'm assuming that you have a single .scala file and that you have no library dependencies that you need to add to the class path.

```
scalac Foo.scala
```

You should look into some beginner-level language tutorials, since this is very basic. `sbt` is the de-facto standard build manager for scala, and I recommend reading the quick start guide there if you want to do anything more complex than what I've described above. http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/